# Sxml versus xexp, what are the differences and why should I use which?

Tags: racket

Racket supports numerous xml-related formats, among them two different xexp libraries based on structure definitions as well as sexp libraries based on lists.

I want to define and read and write a simple xml-based exchange format for rich text without any special validation or DTDs. The purpose is to make the format compatible with other implementation languages and future proof for my own work. (It's about exporting the contents of text% snips in order to avoid a dependence on the proprietary and undocumented WXME format, which could cause huge problems in the future if I change the implementation language.)

**Which library and format should I use for this? xexp or sxml? Or are they both equally well-suited?**

Comment: Consider raising the issue of the WXME format on the mailing list. BTW I think "proprietary" is the wrong word to use.

Comment: I agree "proprietary" is not right word. The problem is that text% really needs an interchange format that other languages could read and write. Maybe I'll raise this issue on the mailing list, but in my experience foundational "requests" that require some real work usually result in the (not necessarily unreasonable) reply: Yes, you should definitely write a package for that and put it online. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neil Van Dyke's [`sxml-intro` package documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/sxml-intro/index.html) describes the differences between the various XML representations in pretty good detail.

Comment: It doesn't really answer which library you should use in what scenario and for what purpose. In fact, I came here right after I had read his introduction, because it was so confusing. To put it bluntly (but with kudos to Neil Van Dykes great work!), I don't need to know whether something counts as sxml or not, I need to know which library is adequate for what purpose / which ones are outdated or superseeded.

Comment: @Eric'3ToedSloth', the `sxml` library has handled most of what I've wanted to do in the past, although I've needed other libraries for parsing HTML. The main tools I've used are XPath (`sxpath`) for extracting information from a document and `pre-post-order` (and maybe `sxml:modify`) to modify documents.